# Unity Collision Behavior

Tags: unity-game-engine, physics

In Unity I noticed that the collision boxes of two moving objects are intersecting and entering each other physically. Is this a normal behaviour?

Also, changing the collision detection to `Continuous` has little to no effect.

Comment: The `CollisionDetectionMode` should be `ContinuousDynamic` on the fast-moving objects and `Continuous` on the objects it will collide with.

Answer (score 2):

Yes.

http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Components/class-PhysicsManager.html

> **Min Penetration For Penalty**   How deep in meters are two objects allowed
>   to penetrate before the collision solver pushes them apart. A higher
>   value will make objects penetrate more but reduces jitter.